# Azure Api Management: Postman Can still access my API, How to Restrict POSTMAN?

Tags: cors, postman, azure-api-management

I have an app that calls an API to get the username and password of a certain service (Azure Function). I created the Azure API & Azure Function in order to hide the credentials in the html/javascript code (the web app). The credentials are coming out of the Azure Function via Json and are sent to my web app via the API. However, the issue with this solution is that POSTMAN is still able to access my API and as a result display the credentials (something any respected developer would be able to do)

I tried the following so far with no avail:

1. Have a CORS setting that allows only one website to access my API. See setting below.
2. Restrict my Azure Function to allow only the IP address of the API Management service. This does not work bec the postman can merely call the api.

In both cases nothing works. Any help?

[image]

I am wondering though how come POSTMAN can still access my API. How do I restrict it from doing so?

P.S. The only solution I know right now is to let it be and have the API limit the requests but not disable POSTMAN

Comment: Contrary to popular belief, CORS's purpose is _not_ to restrict anything...

Answer (score 3):

CORS is something that is validated client side. The browser knows a request can be malicious (cross site request forgery) and will first send an `OPTIONS` request to validate whether or not it is allowed to make that request.

Postman is a tool for the purpose of testing and doesn't enforce CORS policies.

Comment: so how do you suggest we limit postman from accessing an api?

Comment: You can't. If a browser can access your API you can replicate it with Postman (or other similar tools).

Comment: @NotFound That's beside the point: CORS isn't meant to block requests. For one thing, the browser doesn't systematically preflight all cross-origin requests.

Comment: @jub0bs not sure what you mean. It's certainly the browser that restricts the request. You are correct that there's certain conditions that indicate whether or not a request needs a preflight request, but in the context of the OP where an `X-Functions-Key` header is sent in the requests it'll have apply to all requests to the API sent from other domains.

Comment: @NotFound Sure, but such a request would get blocked without CORS, because the SOP mandates it. CORS's purpose is to relax the SOP, not to block anything.